# Android: Email 'to ' field empty

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am developing an application for a hotel, where in, on booking a room, the app sends an email to the email-id given by the user. Now, i know it will use one of my default email clients, which is the gmail. The problem is, it is showing up with gmail's compose message window, with my message in the message body,but the 'to'field is empty. Any help?

here is the code:

```
public void sendmail(View vw)
    {
        name=et1.getText().toString();
        to=et2.getText().toString();
        phone=et3.getText().toString();
        addr=et4.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Send email", "");
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
          emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Thanks for using our app");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello mr"+name+"We just received an email with your details asking for a reservation:"+phone+"  "+addr+"for room number"+x+"");
          try {
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
              finish();
              Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
           }
           catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], showing the code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL) of `EXTRA_EMAIL`:

> A **String[]** holding e-mail addresses that should be delivered to.

Something like this should work:

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Thanks for using our app");
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello mr"+name+"We just received an email with your details asking for a reservation:"+phone+"  "+addr+"for room number"+x+"");
if (mailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mailIntent);
} else {
    // no e-mail app installed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@to.com"});
```

email intent expects an String array but you're providing a string.So, it's not working in your case!